# Using log4j-1.2-api but log4j1.x classes are not found

Tags: java, maven, log4j

as described by Apache

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, I'm still seeing an error when trying to import

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

According to Apache, this should work?

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Thanks

Comment: have you verified if the .jar was really downloaded by the maven?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put **both** dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and import should be:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.I don't want to re-write all the code that uses log4j. Apache has provided the bridge to log4j2 via the log4j-1.2-api https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

A maven dependency requires a type but the example given by Apache for the bridge API here specifies 'bundle':
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-1.2-api/dependency-info.html

If I do that then I don't get log4j-1.2-api.jar in my dependencies, if I set the type to 'jar' then I do get the jar and the log4j-api-2.9.1.jar and can import org.apache.log4j.